# Error 100 when using the android emulator camera

Tags: android, camera

I have a problem with an Android app I'm creating that is using the camera. I've created a virtual device with os 4.0 and I want to use my webcam as the camera. The first time I open my app on the emulator, this is working good, however, after that, the app crashes with "error 100". My application is targeted for os 10.

I've already searched for a workaround or fix for this but I can't find anything about it. Does anyone know a solution? I don't have an actual Android device to test it myself but I'm almost sure it's working on an actual device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera Error 100 - "Media server died. In this case, the application must release the Camera object and instantiate a new one."

Do what the SDK says and release the camera object and make a new one.

[Developer Android Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Read this, too. It might help you: Droid's mediaserver dies on camera.takePicture()

Answer (score 1):

release the `camera` object in instantiate a new one .

Comment: how to release camera object for xamarin?